# Get the number of nonzero elements in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to get the length of the nonzero elements in a numpy array without iterating over the array or masking the array.  Speed is the main goal of calculating the length.

Essentially, something like `len(array).where(array != 0)`.

If it changes the answer, each row will begin with zeros.  The array is filled on the diagonal with zeros.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you mean total number of nonzero elements (and not total number of nonzero rows):

```
In [12]: a = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(100,100))

In [13]: timeit len(a.nonzero()[0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 306 us per loop

In [14]: timeit (a != 0).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 46 us per loop
```

or even better:

```
In [22]: timeit np.count_nonzero(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 39 us per loop
```

This last one, `count_nonzero`, seems to behave well when the array is small, too, whereas the `sum` trick not so much:

```
In [33]: a = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(10,10))

In [34]: timeit len(a.nonzero()[0])
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.18 us per loop

In [35]: timeit (a != 0).sum()
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 us per loop

In [36]: timeit np.count_nonzero(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 686 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

`len(np.nonzero(array)[0])` ?

- [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) returns a tuple of indices, whose length is equal to the number of dimensions in the initial array
- we get just the indices along the first dimension with `[0]`
- compute its length with `len`

Comment: does not work for me: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'sum'`